# Display.getRotation() value changes when screen orientation does not

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-orientation

I'm testing Android's accelerometer and came across an issue where the display's orientation value is alternating, even though my phone is in a static landscape orientation.

Here is the Activity's code:

```
public class AccelerometerTest extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
{
    private final int SENSOR_SAMPLE_RATE = 1000;
    long lastSense;

    int screenRotation;
    static final int ACCELEROMETER_AXIS_SWAP[][] = { 
        {1, -1, 0, 1},      //Rotation 0.
        {-1, -1, 1, 0},     //Rotation 90.
        {-1, 1, 0, 1},      //Rotation 180.
        {1, 1, 1, 0}};      //Rotation 270.

    StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        textView = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(textView);
        lastSense = 0;

        SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        if (sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size() == 0)
        {
            textView.setText("No accelerometer installed.");
        }//if
        else
        {
            Sensor accelerometer = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
            if (!sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME))
            {
                textView.setText("Couldn't register sensor listener.");
            }//if
        }//else
    }//onCreate

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        WindowManager wmgr = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        screenRotation = wmgr.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    }//onResume

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
    {
        if (lastSense == 0)
        {
            lastSense = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        }//if

        if (!((Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - lastSense) > SENSOR_SAMPLE_RATE))
        {
            return;
        }//if

        final int[] acc_swap = ACCELEROMETER_AXIS_SWAP[screenRotation];
        float screenX = (float)acc_swap[0] * event.values[acc_swap[2]]; 
        float screenY = (float)acc_swap[1] * event.values[acc_swap[3]]; 
        float screenZ = event.values[2];

        sbuilder.setLength(0);
        sbuilder.append("Adjusting : Not Adjusting\n");
        sbuilder.append(screenX +" :X: " + event.values[0] + "\n");
        sbuilder.append(screenY +" :Y: " + event.values[1] + "\n");
        sbuilder.append(screenZ +" :Z: " + event.values[2] + "\n");
        textView.setText(sbuilder.toString());

        lastSense = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    }//onSensorChanged

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) { /* Do nothing. */ }
}//AccelerometerTest
```

I came across this issue when I was debugging. I set the first breakpoint here:

```
screenRotation = wmgr.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

This is the only location where the variable `screenRotation` is set. It has an initial value of 0(`ROTATION_0`) when the activity starts. Upon rotating the screen clockwise 90 degrees to landscape, the value is set to 3(`ROTATION_270`). While my phone's landscape orientation stays constant, `onResume()` is never called and thus `screenRotation`'s value *should* never change... Right?

However, when I set the second breakpoint here:

```
final int[] acc_swap = ACCELEROMETER_AXIS_SWAP[screenRotation];
```

The `screenRotation` value alternates from 0 to 3 when I check its value each time the breakpoint hits. As you can see above, I've set up the code to only execute the second breakpoint line every second. Does anyone know why `screenRotation` is alternating values  in a static landscape orientation even though my code is never reassigning its value?